# GhostScript Unrecoverable error: invalidfileaccess in .addcontrolpath

Tags: ghostscript

I installed ghostscript on windows and added it to path variable but I'm still getting

`gs is not recognizes as internal or external command`

I tried to run the .exe file to check the installation and it says

```
This software us supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file COPYING for details.
Unrecoverable error: invalidfileaccess in .addcontrolpath

Close this window with the close button on the title bar or the system menu.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the Ghostscript executable is not called 'gs', it's called one of gswin32/gswin32c/gswin64/gswin64c, depending on whether you are using the 32 or 64-bit version and the command line or windowed executable.

So the error message doesn't make a lot of sense, **unless** it's coming from some other application. In which case you are presumably running something written for, or ported from, Linux. Or, of course, you are trying to run it from the shell by executing 'gs' when you should be using the actual executable name. If that's the case, try using the correct name.

More puzzling still is that the title of this question doesn't appear anywhere in your question body. You don't mention an invalidfileaccess, nor do you quote the back channel from Ghostscript which would give some clue what you are doing.

We really need to know more about what you are doing that doesn't work.